# Trying to take my current page file name and insert it into a redirect (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

here is my code

```
var url = window.location.pathname;

var CurrentPage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);    

if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "mobile/********CurrentPage**********";
}
```

I am getting the page file name as the variable CurrentPage and i want to then recall that variable into the url when the screen size is smaller than 800 to redirect to the mobile site and corresponding file name within the mobile directory… i just don't know how to present the variable in the window.location after mobile/

I just typed ********CurrentPage********** as placeholder to direct you towards where i am having the issue, am i going in the correct direction or way off?

cheers

Comment: So you want the `CurrentPage` variable in the string for `window.location`? If so: `window.location = 'mobile/' + CurrentPage;`

Comment: Thank  you so much, that worked perfectly!

Comment: I've added it as an answer, please mark as accepted when you can

Comment: Done! Thanks again, and thanks for the extra help on placing var's in the middle of strings, that will help me in the future i am sure :-)

Comment: No problem, have fun learning Javascript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to concatenate your string in order to add the variable:

```
window.location = 'mobile/' + CurrentPage
```

Basically, this means you need to close the string and use the `+` operand to add your variable.

You will need to do this whenever you are working with variables in strings. For example, you can place a variable in the middle of strings:

```
var baz = 'hello';
var foo = 'bar' + baz + 'bazzy';
```

In this instance, `foo` would equal `barhellobazzy`